# What is the "Cleanup" badge?

Tags: support, badges

The description for this says it is: "First rollback"; however I have no idea what this means. Could someone explain?

Comment: From time to time, certain users become really addicted to the editing feature, and start making truly silly edits just to highlight words - that only produces pointless churn. But sooner or later they carelessly break things in an edit, leaving dangling words, removing key qualifiers, etc - then someone has to go and cleanup by rolling back to the last version of the question which fully captured the original author's message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit less prevalent now that edits are peer reviewed. However, if someone edited a post in such a way that was not productive, you could "rollback" the revision to the last good version.

Click on the "edited on **********" link on an edited post, and all previous revisions will show a set of links: `source edit rollback link`. The rollback simply discards all revisions after the version that you are rolling back to.

The last time I remember using it was for undoing some excessive retagging of a question.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me.